# PHP Regex: find all consecutive number sequences in a string?

Tags: php, regex

Not sure if regular expressions are the right approach for this, but here is what I am looking to achieve... within a string composed of sorted digits such as **234**121**6789**4125**123** I would like to extract all sequences of at least 3 consecutive digits:

- 234
- 6789
- 123

Can this be done with regex? Otherwise what could be a sensible approach?

Comment: Regex doesn’t have any concept of “consecutive digits”. _“Otherwise what could be a sensible approach?”_ - loop over the whole thing character by character, and if it is a digit and the previous one was also a digit, and exactly one less, then …? Keep a counter of how many of such consecutive digits you currently got, and if more than three, output the whole bunch when you encounter the next non-digit or lesser digit character …?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick feedback! Alright your proposal for the alternative is also what I had considered. Was just curious to understand if regex could do that.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667735/php-preg-match-all-how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-or-seperated-substrings-w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With RegEx, you can use:

```
(123(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?|234(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?|345(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?|456(?:7(?:89?)?)?|567(?:89?)?|6789?|789)
```

Try here: https://regex101.com/r/Ap8C2D/1

If you test also with 012…:

```
(012(?:3(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?)?|123(?:4(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?)?|234(?:5(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?)?|345(?:6(?:7(?:89?)?)?)?|456(?:7(?:89?)?)?|567(?:89?)?|6789?|789)
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/zm6I9x/1

Comment: Depending on the usage you could leave out the outer group.

Answer (score 2):

You could use RegEx, but to be honest this would be much simpler to implement a loop and check if the numbers are sequential inside of the loop. Take a look at this example:

```
$literal = '23412167894125123';

for ($c = 0; $c < strlen($literal) - 2; $c++) {
    if(intval($literal[$c]) + 1 == intval($literal[$c + 1]) &&
       intval($literal[$c]) + 2 == intval($literal[$c + 2])) {
        echo $literal[$c], $literal[$c + 1], $literal[$c + 2], '<br />';
    }
}
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/SvIOo)

Answer (score 1):

If the regex looks too complex, this function uses a simple for loop

```
function findSeq($string) {

    $seq_started = false;

    $seq = '';

    $list = [];

    for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($string) + 1; $i++) {

        @$curr = $string[$i];
        $prev = $string[$i - 1];
        @$next = $string[$i + 1];

        if ($prev + 1 == $curr) {

            if ($seq_started === false) {

                $seq .= "$prev$curr";

            } else {

                $seq .= $curr;
            }

            $seq_started = true;

            continue;

        }

        if ($seq_started === true) {

            if (strlen($seq) > 2) {

                $list[] = $seq;

            }

            $seq = '';

            $seq_started = false;

        }

    }

    return $list;

}

print_r(findSeq('2341216789412501231456789'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 234
    [1] => 6789
    [2] => 0123
    [3] => 456789
)
```