# PHP: preg_match_all() - how to find all occurrences of OR seperated substrings with a regex correctly?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-match-all

My task is to find all consecutive number in a string of only numbers. However I am not searching for a better regex to do this, but for a correct regex of matching substrings.

This is how I build my regex:

```
$regex = "";

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    $str = "";
    for($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
        if($a > $i) {
            $str .= $a;
            if(strlen($str)>1) {
              $regex .= "|".$str."";
            }
        }
    }
}

$myregex = "/".ltrim($regex,"|")."/";
echo $myregex;
```

Result:

> /12|123|1234|12345|123456|1234567|12345678|123456789|23|234|2345|23456|234567|2345678|23456789|34|345|3456|34567|345678|3456789|45|456|4567|45678|456789|56|567|5678|56789|67|678|6789|78|789|89/

Then I do:

```
$literal = '234121678941251236544567812122345678';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all($myregex,$literal,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(13) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "23"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "67"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "89"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [6]=>
    string(2) "45"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "67"
    [8]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [9]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [10]=>
    string(2) "23"
    [11]=>
    string(2) "45"
    [12]=>
    string(2) "67"
  }
}
```

However I want to find all substrings occuring (and not go to the next chars after a match) - like:

> 23,234,34,12,67,678,6789,78,789,89,12, ...

However I have tried different variatons with brackets, +, ... and did not figure out the correct regex to find *all* matches (sorry, still bit of a regex noob). How do I have to modify the regular expression?

Comment: There's no way to get overlapping matches AFAIK. You'll have to split your `$liiteral` number pool manually, then assert each substring with the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the regex is important.  I'm not sure if this fully solves the issue the method of doing it this way may be fundamentally flawed but you can try this:

```
$regex = [];

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    $str = "";
    for($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
        if($a > $i) {
            $str .= $a;
            if(strlen($str)>1) {
              $regex[] = $str;
            }
        }
    }
}

usort($regex, function($a,$b){
    return strlen($b) <=> strlen($a);
});

$myregex = '/'.implode('|', $regex).'/';
```

What it does is make the number sequences an array, then it sorts them by length and orders them the longest sequences first.   The end result is this (after matching)

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "234"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "6789"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "45678"
    [6]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [8]=>
    string(7) "2345678"
  }
}
```

Also note the spaceship operator `<=>` only works in PHP7+

Hope it helps.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c048a710cf64e5c18c1e186a2dc22b27cb0df05c)

> and not go to the next chars after a match

I don't think this is possible with regex, if you mean you want to find `23` `234` `2345` all at once in `2345607` for example.  However if it matches a long sequence it only stands to reason that it must match a shorter one, logically.  So you could just trim off the right hand number until the length is 2 and get the matches.

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted as I try to match ALL possible substrings with a regex but it is better as my initial approach as it checks for longer literals first. Also thanks for the spaceship operator did not know that yet 

Comment: If you know the longest match, then logically you have all the matches. As long as the smaller matches are all subsets of each larger match.

Comment: True - if it matches a longer one it also must match the corresponding shorter ones therefore I just have to split up the matches with the regex again recursivley and all matches are there. Not perfect as an additional function is required but good enough.

Comment: You can use `substr($match,0,-1)` and remove the right most number until only 2 numbers are left.

Comment: You also don't need preg_match_all just preg_match would work.  preg_match_all is for use on multi-line strings.  Not for finding all the matches in single line string.  Here is a good example of what preg_match_all is for, https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/HtmlMinifier.php this uses a large string of HTML and minifies is.